# Вывести 6 бит целого числа А, начиная со 2-ого

Tags: c++

Никак не могу вникнуть в суть этих побитовых операций. Здесь, по идее, нужно указать некую маску(прошу объяснить, как его кушают, я, вероятно, не понимаю, что это вообще такое) и ориентируясь на неё выводить биты из числа. Но как мне верно указать маску? Юзер же, к примеру не должен сам думать какую маску подобрать для его числа... Или здесь вообще всё по другому следовало сделать?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");
int num, mask = 50;
char tmp[33];
cout << "Введите число a: " << endl;
cin >> num;
_itoa_s(num, tmp, 2);
cout << "Число a в двоичном виде: " << tmp << endl;
_itoa_s(mask, tmp, 2);
cout << "Маска для a: " << tmp << endl;
_itoa_s ((num & mask) >> 1, tmp, 2);
cout << "Выделенные биты a: " << tmp << endl;

}
```

Comment: Вам надо сдвинуть число вправо на одну позицию при усорвии, что биты нумерутся с 1,  или на две позиции, если они нумеруются с 0, и применить к нему операцию & с маской 0x3f

Comment: Всё, я, вроде бы разобрался. Благодарю. Просто тупил, что же являет собой эта маска.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно вывести на консоль 6 битов, начиная с бита 2 (нумерация битов идет с 0, хотя для данной задачи это не существенно), то это просто сделать, используя стандартный класс `std::bitset`, не используя никакой маски.

Например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main() 
{
    unsigned int x = 0b100010011000;
    std::bitset<6> bits( x >> 2 );

    std::cout << bits << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод на консоль будет

```
100110
```

Если ваш компилятор не поддерживает двоичные литералы, то в этой демонстрационной программе вместо двоичного литерала в качестве теста вы можете использовать шестнадцатиричный литерал. Например,

```
    unsigned int x = 0x898;
```

В противном случае, если не использовать класс `std::bitset`, вам придется написать и использовать маску в виде

```
const unsigned int MASK = 0x3f;
```

А затем использовать выражения

```
( x >> 2 ) & MASK
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!  Это было в самом деле просто.

Comment: @droppenheimer Не за что.:)